# Puting MudAutocomplete in MudBlazor Datagrid

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I want to a \chieve a sales form in Blazor wasm, inside the form I've order Information like:

1. OrderID, 2. CustomerName, 3. OrderDate, TotalAmount.....etc.

below the OrderInfo, I've MudDataGrid which contains order details such as: ProductName, Quantity, UnitPrice and Total Amount.

inside the MudDataGrid, I've a MudAutocomplete which searchs the Product from a a list.

I can search the product in the autocomplete, when I select a product from the list I want to populate the unit price and Product Info to current row of the MudDataGrid.

how can I achieve this?, Please help.

these are my  model entities :

this is my MudDataGri

```cs
<MudDataGrid T="OrderDetailModel" Items="@model.OrderDetails" ReadOnly="false" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell"
             CommittedItemChanges="@CommittedItemChanges" Bordered="true" Dense="true" EditTrigger="DataGridEditTrigger.Manual" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Column">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ProductName" Title="Product">
            <EditTemplate>
                <MudAutocomplete T="ProductModel" ToStringFunc="@(productList => productList.ProductName)"
                                Value="selectedProduct"
                                SearchFunc="@SearchProduct"
                                ValueChanged="ProductChanged"                                                                 
                                ResetValueOnEmptyText="false"
                                CoerceText="false" CoerceValue="true"
                                Placeholder="Search Product"
                                Immediate="true"
                                AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search"
                                AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
                                Variant="Variant.Text" ShowProgressIndicator="true" ProgressIndicatorColor="Color.Primary" />

            </EditTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quantity" Title="Quanity">
            <EditTemplate>
                <MudNumericField @bind-Value="context.Item.Quantity"
                                Adornment="Adornment.End"
                                AdornmentText="KG/PC"
                                TextChanged="@(()=> CommittedItemChanges(context.Item))"
                                Immediate="true" />
            </EditTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.UnitPrice" Title="Unit Price" Format="C">
            <EditTemplate>
                <MudNumericField @bind-Value="context.Item.UnitPrice"
                                Adornment="Adornment.End"
                                AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Preview"
                                OnAdornmentClick="@(()=> CheckPriceDetail(context.Item))"
                                TextChanged="@(()=> CommittedItemChanges(context.Item))"
                                Format="F2"
                                Immediate="true" />
            </EditTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.TotalAmount" Title="Total Amount" IsEditable="false" Format="C" />

    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>
```

this is search product

```cs
private async Task<IEnumerable<ProductModel>> SearchProduct(string value)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return _productsList;

                return _productsList.Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
            }
```

this is Product Changed Code

```cs
private async Task ProductChanged(ProductModel value /*, OrderDetailModel item*/)
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    selectedProduct = value;

                    //item.ProductID = selectedProduct.ID;
                    //item.ProductName = selectedProduct.ProductName;
                    //item.UnitPrice = selectedProduct.UnitPrice;               

                }

            }
```